# JavaScript While loop will not print results properly to console

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop, break

My problem is with my second function called `sum`. However, here is the complete explanation:

`range` function takes `start` and `end` numbers of a range as parameters and fills `rangeArray[]` with entire range.

`sum` function takes an array as parameter and adds all numbers in the array.

My `sum` function is executing the job properly (replace `return` with `console.log()` to see this), but I would rather have the while loop print one final number (num) after the while loop breaks.

right now it is only printing 10 to the console (I suspect because it is printing the last element in array + 0, which is 10 in this case).

tl;dr

why is `console.log(n)` not working after the while loop after function `sum` breaks?

```js
rangeArray = []

function range(start, end) {

  i = 0
  while (i < end) {
    rangeArray.push(start)
    i = i + 1
    start = start + 1
  }

}

range(1, 10)

function sum(array) {

  num = 0
  i = 0
  lastIndex = array.length - 1

  while (i <= lastIndex) {
    return num = num + array.pop()
    i++
  }
  console.log(n)

}

sum(rangeArray)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `return` from the `while` loop, this will return from the function `sum` and the next line `console.log` will not execute.

Another problem is, you're logging `n`, where the name of the variable is `num`.

```js
rangeArray = []

function range(start, end) {

  i = 0
  while (i < end) {
    rangeArray.push(start)
    i = i + 1
    start = start + 1
  }

}

range(1, 10)

function sum(array) {

  num = 0
  i = 0
  lastIndex = array.length - 1

  while (i <= lastIndex) {
    num = num + array.pop()
    i++
  }
  document.write(num);
}

sum(rangeArray);
```

If you're looking for optimized solution:

```js
function sum(start, end) {
  var total = 0;

  while (start <= end) {
    total += start++;
    // Add the start value to total
    // Increment the start value by one
  }

  document.write(total);
  return total;
}

var total = sum(1, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `return` in the while loop, which returns the value of the first item in the array as the value of sum

```js
function range(start, end) {
  var rangeArray = [],
    i = start; //use var to create it as a local variable
  while (i <= end) {
    rangeArray.push(i);
    i++;
  }
  return rangeArray;
}

var rangeArray = range(1, 10)
snippet.log('range: ' + rangeArray)

function sum(array) {

  var num = 0,
    i = 0,
    len = array.length

  while (i < len) {
    num += array[i];
    i++
  }
  snippet.log('sum: ' + num)
  return num;
}

sum(rangeArray)
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

You can write it more cleanly like

```js
function range(start, end) {
  var rangeArray = [],
    i = start; //use var to create it as a local variable
  while (i <= end) {
    rangeArray.push(i);
    i++;
  }
  return rangeArray;
}

var rangeArray = range(1, 10)
snippet.log('range: ' + rangeArray)

function sum(array) {
  var num = array.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b
  });
  return num;
}

var val = sum(rangeArray);
snippet.log('sum: ' + val)
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```